# php working locally and remotely on own hosting, but not remotely on client's hosting

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not good with PHP, so please bear with me. I have the following code:

```
<?php $thisPage="designers";
include("phpincludes/header.php") ?>

<div id="contentLeft">
<?echo "<h2><a href='designer_display.php?d_name=".$_GET['d_name']."'>" . $_GET['d_name']. "</a></h2>";?>

<?
    error_reporting(0);
    require_once "phpincludes/connection.php";

    $designer = $_GET['d_name'];
    // Category Selection Start.
    $cat_qry = "SELECT DISTINCT (
        `own_category`
    )
    FROM  `products` 
    WHERE  `designer` ='".$designer."' && own_category !=  ''";
        $rs_qry = mysql_query($cat_qry);

            $i = 0;

        while($rec_qry = mysql_fetch_array($rs_qry))
        {
          if($i==0)
            $first_cat = $rec_qry['cat_name'];
            $cat_name[$i]=$rec_qry['cat_name'];
            $i++;
        }

        // Category Selection Start.
        $cat_name = $_GET['catName1'];
        $cat_qry =  "SELECT DISTINCT (
        `own_category`
        )
        FROM  `products` 
            WHERE  `designer` ='".$designer."' && own_category !=  ''";


            //"select * from categories";
            $rs_qry = mysql_query($cat_qry);
            $rec_no = mysql_affected_rows();

            /*if($_GET["catName1"]=="")
                $catName = $first_cat;
            else
                $catName = $cat_name;*/

            $n1 = 1;
            echo "<ul id=\"designers\">";
            while($rec_qry = mysql_fetch_array($rs_qry))
            {
                 $cate_name = str_replace('_',' ',$rec_qry['own_category']);

                 //print_r($cate_name[1]);
                 if($rec_qry["own_category"]!= $_GET['catName'])
                    echo "<li><A HREF='d_items.php?no=".$n1."&d_name=".$designer."&catName=".$rec_qry["own_category"]."'>".strtoupper($cate_name)."</A></li>";
                 else
                    echo "<li><A HREF='d_items.php?no=".$n1."&d_name=".$designer."&catName=".$rec_qry["own_category"]."'><font color='#8d9354'>".strtoupper($cate_name)."</font></a></li>";

                 if($rec_qry["own_category"]== $_GET['catName'])
                 {
                     $query="SELECT A.photo_filename, A.photo_title, B.dc_cat_name FROM displays A
                                LEFT JOIN displays_categories B ON B.dc_display_photos = A.photo_filename
                                WHERE dc_cat_name ='".$rec_qry["cat_name"]."'";
                      $query="SELECT B.pro_name, B.own_category, B.own_photo_filename from categories as A LEFT JOIN 
                             products as B ON A.cat_name = B.own_category
                             where cat_name ='".$_GET["catName"]."' and designer ='".$designer."' order by B.pro_name";
                    $rs1_qry = mysql_query($query);        

                    echo "<ul class=\"items\">";
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs1_qry))
                    {

                    if ($designer == "Jardan") {

                         $p1name = str_ireplace($designer,'',$row["pro_name"]);
                         $pname = substr($p1name, 0, -3);

                    } else {         

                         $pname = str_ireplace($designer,'',$row["pro_name"]);
                     }                          

                         if($_GET['ProName'] != $row["pro_name"])
                            echo "<li><A HREF='d_item_details.php?d_name=".$designer."&ProName=".$row['pro_name']."&catName1=".$rec_qry['own_category']."&catName=".$rec_qry['own_category']."'>".$pname."</A></li>";
                         else
                                 echo "<li><A HREF='d_item_details.php?d_name=".$designer."&ProName=".$row['pro_name']."&catName1=".$rec_qry['own_category']."&catName=".$rec_qry['own_category']."'><font color='#fff'>".$pname."</font></A></li>";                
                    }
                    echo "</ul>";
                 }
            }
            echo "</ul>";



        $f=1;
        $recnm = $_GET['ProName'];
        $owncat = $_GET['catName1'];
        $photo_title = $_GET['ptitle'];
        $query2="SELECT pro_code, pro_dimensions, own_photo_filename, designer_pdf, palette FROM products 
            WHERE pro_name ='".$recnm."' and own_category ='".$owncat."'";
        $rt2=mysql_query($query2); 
        echo mysql_error();

    ?>
        </div>
        <div id="contentRight">

        <?
            while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($rt2))
            {
        ?>          

                    <?$d = explode(' ',$designer);
                     for($p=0;$p<count($d);$p++)
                     {
                        $des.=$d[$p];
                     }


                    if ($designer == "Playstar") {

                     $p2name = str_ireplace($designer,'',$recnm);
                     $poname = substr($p2name, 0, -3);

                    } else {         

                     $poname = str_ireplace($designer,'',$recnm);
                     }                          


                     ?>
                    <img class="lighting" src="img/designers/<?echo $des."/".$row2['own_photo_filename'];?>.jpg" />
        <div class="mailerBtn"><a href="mailto:info@clientsite.com.au?subject=<?echo $recnm;?>"><h4>ENQUIRE</h4></a>
        <a href="pdf/<?echo $des."/".$row2['designer_pdf'];?>.pdf" target="_blank"><h4>Download Product PDF</h4></a></div>

                    <h3><?echo $poname;?></h3>
                    <p>
                        <? 
                                 echo "<b>Product code:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;". $row2['pro_code']."<BR>";
                        if ($designer == "Playstar") {

                                 echo $row2['pro_dimensions'];
                     } else {        

                                 echo "<b>Dimensions:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;". $row2['pro_dimensions'];
                     }  ?>

                    </p>
                    <? if($row2[4]=='yes') {
                    ?>
                        <img class="palette" src="img/designers/<?echo $des."/".$row2['own_photo_filename'];?>-palette.jpg" />
                    <? } ?>

        <?}?>
<?php include("phpincludes/base.php") ?>
```

Much of the code was written by someone else, but I've been modifying it in a couple of ways. It works locally (on XAMP) and on my personal site where I've been hosting it as a test site.

But when i uploaded it to the client's host, this page stops abruptly at `echo "<ul class=\"items\">";` - roughly line 73. I can't see what's stopping it from running properly.

Some assistance would be gratefully received!

MTIA.

Comment: no chance they're on host gator are they? Joking aside, many cheaper hosts can have odd configurations or older php versions that could interfere. you can compare your php settings by adding die(php_info()); at the top of this page to see what the difference is

Comment: Is the data in database same as your localhost? I mean exactly the same. And when you "view page source", what is the last line it show?

Comment: Thanks guys - @royrui, yes the db is exactly the same. @Kai Qing, you're right - I should've tried that first!

Comment: part right. there's no underscore in the function. phpinfo() is correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's hard to tell. It's very obviously something with the clients setup.

Taking a wild guess, that client is still running **PHP4**. Because after line 73 you have a call to [`str_ireplace`](http://php.net/str_ireplace) which wasn't available for that.

You would likely get a fatal error for this one. And this is the right avenue for investigation here. Add this on top for debugging (instead of `error_reporting(0)` which is not so helpful):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_WARNING);
```

And ask for errors. Better yet, provide a custom error handler which prints out something shiny for end user-type clients. Otherwise ask for the `error.log` which should contain the exact error likewise.

Comment: Mario, I could kiss you. Thank you! I just replaced str_ireplace with str_replace and all is good. Will accept answer after required time.

Comment: Well in that case you might benefit from http://upgradephp.berlios.de/ or http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_Compat to replicate some baseline PHP5 functions on your setup. That's better than rewriting stuff or using less versatile functions.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid using the "short tags" `<?` and replace with the regular `<?php` tags. At a minimum, on that line not having a space after the "?" is asking for trouble, but overall you should just replace the short tags as they can cause trouble for various reasons and many installations do not have them enabled by default.

FYI, one specific case where they often cause trouble is for XHTML documents, if the xml declaration isn't printed with PHP, it will throw an error. Now with HTML5 I guess this will be less of an issue, but IMHO, best practice would be to avoid them.

Answer (score 1):

Glad you got it working, but  I wouldn't be using this code in production on your clients web host.

```
$f=1;
$recnm = $_GET['ProName'];
$owncat = $_GET['catName1'];
$photo_title = $_GET['ptitle'];
$query2="SELECT pro_code, pro_dimensions, own_photo_filename, designer_pdf, palette FROM products  WHERE pro_name ='".$recnm."' and own_category ='".$owncat."'";
```

This and all the other queries here are vulnerably to sql injection. (if I passed in catName1='; DELETE * FROM products where 1=1 or '2'='2)

You need to either convert the queries to paramaterised queries, or use mysql_real_escape_string.

ie

```
 $owncat = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['ProName']);
```

Comment: Cool, thanks for pointing that out Haz. Am amending the code as suggested!

Comment: Likewise, you've got some XSS vulnerabilities in there you'll want to seal off.  See this line for one example:

<h2><a href='designer_display.php?d_name=".$_GET['d_name']."'>

To get the gist about XSS, check out the Wikipedia page on it (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).  Also, there are quite a few threads about it on SO as well, so you may want to read up.

Comment: I think the editor "ate" some of my markup above, but I think you get the idea :)